# How to make Eevee viewport background transparent?

Tags: transparency, eevee-render-engine

I would like to view my meshes in Eevee rendered viewport with an alpha background when using HDRI lighting.

How do I use HDRI lighting without seeing the HDRI image in the background of my Eevee viewport?

Answer (score 3):

You can use chosen color for EEVEE viewport using **Light Path** trick.

In the **Shader Editor**, go to **World** view and mix **HDRI Background** with **Solid Color Background** using **Is Camera Ray**. This way your HDRI will have influence over the scene, but it will not be visible in viewport/camera.

To make it transparent you can set **Alpha** in **Solid Background Color** to **0** but it will be pure black color then.

[image: nodes]

If you want to render with actual transparent background you will need to set **Film** > **Alpha** to **Transparent**:

[image: film]